# Adding xUnit Support for ReSharper

Tags: resharper, xunit

I have VS 2013 and ReSharper 8.2
I am trying to add xUnit support extension for resharper but I can not find it.

It is the only place to get it AFAIK 
Am I doing something wrong?

It should be there...
https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/xunitcontrib/Download

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This bug is fixed, and the 8.2 feed is working as expected - you should be able to find the package without any trouble.

Unfortunately, there's currently a bug in the gallery which means the index for the 8.2 feed loses items over time. I'm hoping to have it fixed this week, but in the meantime, I can rebuild the index manually to get it working. If you still don't see it, you can ping me on twitter (@citizenmatt) and I can rebuild it again.